# Local cache server Windows 10

Tags: networking, dns, cache

It's been a while since I've asked a question (or participated at all) on SE but here I am again.

Long story short the internet at my Squadron's home base is garbage.  I have an HP Proliant DL360 G5 server I'm not using.  It has plenty of CPU, RAM, and HDD for what I'm proposing (I think).

I want to connect this server to the network and use it to cache certain sites locally, to improve load times.  *Ideally* the server would detect which sites are accessed most often and store those locally, dynamically changing what it has locally based on what people request.

If I can't have it dynamically determine what people use, I can manually specify frequently used sites.

And I want it to be seamless too.  For instance, if User A opens www.blahblah.com on their own device, the server should serve up its own copy rather than fetching from WAN.  This solution would preferably work even if users are using custom DNS, such as 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4.

Also *ideally* the server should determine how often a page changes so it can determine whether or not to serve up the local copy or the WAN copy based on how often the page changes.

Before you quote me military policies and all, I have full security clearance to do this project.

Server specs:

2x Intel Xeon E5440 quad-core @ 2.83 GHz
22GB ECC DDR2 FB-DIMM (4x4GB + 2x2GB + 2x1GB)
~650GB RAID5 array with 6x146GB 15K HDDs
2x700W Redundant PSUs
2x1000BaseT Ethernet
LiO2 interface (sidenote, it would be nice to get this working!  I don't know how to make it work)
XFX R5 230
Windows 10 Enterprise

I would prefer to run Windows 10, but I can also run it in a VM on any OS.

Comment: Come on people I kind of need a solution for this.